# How do I give a program permission to change the system time in windows 7?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a some software which requires that the windows system time be synchronized with a physical atomic clock* before a certain procedure begins.

Right now the user has instructions to modify the time using `timedate.cpl` before they begin.

I would like to display an hour and minute input box and allow the user to click a button when the times match just as you would do if you were starting a countdown. This makes it easier to extract the time as soon as they click on my button. To achieve this I would like to run a system command like this:

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator "time 12:34"
```

However, when I test this it asks me for a password.

I would like to know if there some way give my program the just the right to set the time without needing to type a password everytime?

Note:

- the software is run as the logged in user
- it must be possible to run the procedure stand-alone (E.g. the pc could be used at a remote location).
- the user is not part of a windows domain

<sub>* Atomic clocks are suitable because the time does not drift much over a long period of time. Precision is not a factor. Until now operators actually write the time on a piece of paper before starting a step.</sub>

Comment: @tegbains: That appears to be a centralized time synchronization issue. Mine is about setting the time offline (no ntp or gps). Perhaps it's a duplicate of something else but I could not find anything when I searched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't specify whether these machines are part of an Active Directory domain or not. I'll assume that they are not.

You don't specify what version of Windows you're running. The pre-Vista and post-Vista cataclysm is huge. It's practically an entirely different operating system. You can't just say "Windows" since Windows has changed a lot in its 20+ year history. I'll assume something Vista or above.

In the example you gave above, you are trying to run a program as Administrator, and to do that, you must supply the password for Administrator. There is not a direct equivalent of sudo in Windows. There does not exist a good way to embed Administrator credentials in the script or obfuscate them in some way that does not dangerously risk exposing the password to the standard user.

Anyway, you don't give permissions or access rights to programs. You give permissions to users, who execute programs. These programs execute in the security context of that user. The programs inherit their security privileges from the user who executed them.

You would use either Group Policy or Local Computer Policy (secpol.msc) to delegate this right to a user or group. You need to edit the **Computer Configuration** ⇒ **Windows Settings** ⇒ **Local Policies** ⇒ **User Rights Assignment** ⇒ **Change the system time** setting.

[image: SeSystemtimePrivilege]

The technical name of the privilege is the [`SeSystemtimePrivilege`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/change-the-system-time) user right.

*But wait there's more!* Changing the system time is a privileged operation, and a user can cause a lot of havoc with the ability to change the system time, either maliciously or accidentally. Therefore, I do not think at this time you'll be able to change the system time as a standard user.

`NTRights.exe -u JoeBlow +r SeSystemtimePrivilege` from the 2003 Resource Kit basically does the same thing as adding the user to the "Change the system time" list in secpol.msc, and you'll still get the `A required privilege is not held by the client` error. Even if you disable UAC, you still get the error. Keep in mind that the security token of a user is only calculated once at logon, so if you make changes that user's security token, they need to log off and back on again for the changes to take effect. But it doesn't matter - still it will not allow you to change the system time without elevating.

At this point, I would consider doing something like writing a Windows service or a scheduled task that ran as Local System that a standard user could interact with in some way that would manipulate the system time. It's pretty apparent that Windows didn't want standard user's screwing around with the system time.

Comment: Precision is not the reason for the atomic clocks. The clocks have negligible drift. An operator writes down the start time of each  step on a sheet of paper. There are several operators and overall system accuracy is achieved using this method. The whole process is slowly being automated.

Comment: I read that I need to install *resource kit* to make it possible for a non-admin user to change the system time via command line. These seems like a lot of work to do something that is so trivial in linux :(

Comment: Your efforts may be wasted using the native Windows NTP client anyway - depending on how accurate you expect the local clock to be of course. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2007/10/23/high-accuracy-w32time-requirements.aspx

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown If users are changing the time manually, then we can safely assume that precision is not a concern at all.